# How to store date in MongoDB in ISO format instead of Long [Play, Scala and ReactiveMongo]?

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

I'm trying to insert date in MongoDB using following way:

```
collection.insert(Json.obj("user"->"abc", "joined_date" -> DateTime.now))
```

In database:

```
   {                                                       
            "_id" : ObjectId("5865d99718969bca6a09450f"),   
            "user" : "abc",                                 
            "joined_date" : NumberLong("1483069847066")     
    }
```

The problem here is that date is stored in database in Long millisec format but what I want is it to store in ISO Date format.

I have tried in MongoShell persisting the same data `db.example.insert({user:"abc", joined_date:new Date()})` and the result is below:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5865d838a4f98c5bb83b1eb8"),
        "user" : "abc",
        "joined_date" : ISODate("2016-12-30T03:44:56.824Z")
}
```

So, how can I store date in ISODate format in database using ReactiveMongo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using Play JSON to represent MongoDB document (not BSON), and the date is a Joda one converted as JSON number according the Play JSON module.

You can directly use BSON with the driver, and pass the date as [`BSONDateTime`](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/api/#reactivemongo.bson.BSONDateTime).

```
BSONDocument("myDate" -> BSONDateTime(..))
```

Or (assuming a ReactiveMongo version >= 0.11.9) you can use [MongoDB JSON extended representation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#data_date) `$date: date_value` :

```
Json.obj("myDate" -> Json.obj("$date" -> dateTimeLong))
```

The JSON formats supported by the ReactiveMongo serialisation are [documented](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/documentation/json/overview.html).